# A toggle(Switch) in every row of a Ant Design table is not working as excepted

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need a toggle button in every row of a table, and each time it toggles I want to set it to a state. Right now I have written the code as in the sandbox, but here is a problem, whenever I toggle the switch the control is not entering to `onChange`, i.e. `I am here` is not printing every time when I toggle the switch.

SandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-microservice-qd3ku?file=/index.js:797-801

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this . it is working .

```
import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "antd/dist/antd.css";
    import "./index.css";
    import { Table, Switch } from "antd";

    class EditableTable extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.columns = [
          {
            title: "name",
            dataIndex: "name",
            width: "30%",
            editable: true
          },
          {
            align: "right",
            render: (text, record, index) => {
              return <Switch onChange={()=>this.handleChnage()} />;
            }
          }
        ];
        this.state = {
          dataSource: [
            {
              key: "0",
              name: "Edward King 0"
            },
            {
              key: "1",
              name: "Edward King 1"
            }
          ],
          count: 2
        };
      }
      handleChnage = () => {
        console.log("I am here");
      };

      render() {
        const { dataSource } = this.state;
        const columns = this.columns;
        return (
          <Table
            rowClassName={() => "editable-row"}
            bordered
            dataSource={dataSource}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={false}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<EditableTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```